# Push elements into existing array in React Hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

let's say I have an array

```
const defaultList = [
  {
    "name":"John",
    "last_name":"doe"
  },
  {
    "name":"Alice",
    "last_name":"Smith"
  }
]
```

I want using `for` loop to add new value `online`, so in the end it will look like this

```
const defaultList = [
      {
        "name":"John",
        "last_name":"doe",
        "online":"yes"
      },
      {
        "name":"Alice",
        "last_name":"Smith",
         "online":"no"
      }
    ]
```

I am using React Hooks and array is defined in this way, where later I fill it with data above:

```
const [defaultList, setDefaultList] = useState([]);
```

I would appreciate any idea how to do it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.map`

```
const res = defaultList.map(el => ({ ...el, online: 'yes' })
```

```js
const defaultList = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    last_name: 'doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    last_name: 'Smith'
  }
]

const res = defaultList.map(el => ({ ...el, online: 'yes' }))

console.log(res)
```

---

Or `.forEach` with `Object.assign()`

```
defaultList.forEach(el => {
  Object.assign(el, { online: 'yes' })
})
```

```js
const defaultList = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    last_name: 'doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    last_name: 'Smith'
  }
]

defaultList.forEach(el => {
  Object.assign(el, { online: 'yes' })
})

console.log(defaultList)
```

---

..which is equivalent to the `for..of` loop

```
for (const el of defaultList) {
  Object.assign(el, { online: 'yes' })
}
```

```js
const defaultList = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    last_name: 'doe'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    last_name: 'Smith'
  }
]

for (const el of defaultList) {
  Object.assign(el, { online: 'yes' })
}

console.log(defaultList)
```

---

The difference is that the first method creates the whole new array, while the others is mutating the original one

Comment: The `map` approach is definitely the better choice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 two variables with the same name
Firstly, set default state by:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(defaultList)
```

After change to new list, call setList

```
setList(newDefaultList)
```

Use `list` for what you want instead of `defaultList`